# Problem on creating UInt16 class function that give Type Error Python

Tags: python, types

I would like to make this test program

> test_UInt16.py

```
from data_types import UInt16

def test_UInt16_constructor():

    # default value should be 0
    assert (int(UInt16()) == 0)

    # initialize with arbitrary integer value
    assert (int(UInt16(1 << 8)) == (1 << 8))
```

> data_types.py

```
class UInt16:
   def __init__(self, initial_value=0):
       self.value = initial_value
```

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'UInt16'

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast a `UInt16` object - which you defined - to an `int` object.

You need to change you code to become something like this.

test_UInt16

```
from data_types import UInt16

def test_UInt16_constructor():

    # default value should be 0
    assert (UInt16().value == 0)

    # initialize with arbitrary integer value
    assert (UInt16(1 << 8).value == (1 << 8))
```

UInt16

```
class UInt16:
    def __init__(self, initial_value=0):
        self.value = initial_value
```

Also it's a better practice to use built in test method (`unittest` class)